# Vuex: How To Load Initial State Data From API

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have my state all set up but the initial data I want stored in my store will not load until I change pages in my app. How can I force all of the data to load from the API (using axios) prior to the app loading? I've tried firing my load action in the created and mounted lifecycles of the main app but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?  Unless there's an error, the lifecycle hooks would run.

Comment: You gotta post some code or we have no way of knowing what's wrong. Show your lifecycle hooks and your api call methods.